# React App is not working due to one component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a react app using the command `create-react-app my-app`
and when I build and start its working fine using `npm start`

Now I added one *.JS* file inside the **SRC** folder and used the tag inside **App.Js**
Here is the below code for that component

```
import React from 'react'

        class Footer extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h1>It's a bit chilly out there</h1>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }

        export default Footer;
```

After that I have added the Component into App.JS

```
class App extends React.Component{

  render() {
      return (
        <>
         <div>
              Test Component created using Class
              <Footer/>
          </div>
        
        </>
         
      );
  }
}
export default App;
```

After successfully compilation when I ran my app, I got empty browser and also get error in Console.

[image: Console Error message]

Comment: Is it the name of the file, can you try renaming the file to have all lowercase including the extension or PascalCase with lowercase extension?

Comment: try using `.js` instead of `.Js` - never seen anyone use `.Js` before - if the issue really is the case of the extension, it's an odd error message - but then, react isn't exactly known for clarity

Comment: footer is a tag in HTML. try renaming the file Footer.js to something else

Comment: Can you upvote if it is working for you? @sushmitgos

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshots, i have understood to change the case used to name the react components.

1. Is your footer component named as `Footer.js`
2. Is your App component named as `App.js`

Comment if the above changes worked.